# Ratchet (php) using classes MessageComponentInterface and WampServerInterface together to use websockets and push notifications

Tags: php, push-notification, ubuntu-18.04, ratchet

In the documentation here http://socketo.me/docs/ are 2 samples - one is simple Chat application(http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world), which uses MessageComponentInterface concept as WebSocket server and the second (http://socketo.me/docs/push) is Push application which uses WampServerInterface concept.
I've succeed with installation both of examples.

If I understand right, using the MessageComponentInterface - front-end application can interact with the WS server making queries to it and, using the WampServerInterface - back-end server can interact with the front-end, pushing the messages to it.

Is that possible to combine those concepts in one WebSocket server to have rich application?
Like I want to send the messages to the WS server and, as well, to receive them asynchronously.

Should I just implement both of those interfaces in my custom class and then pass it to the server constructur? Or I should do something different?

Any thoughts are welcome :)

Comment: eventually I want to use function
> public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {} of class MessageComponentInterface <
but from server side

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. There is another php socket library and this library makes everything super easy. php Socket library is https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io

And to send Notifications from server side we need to use https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io-emitter along with **phpsocket.io**

for better explanation check github discussion here https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io/issues/23

hope this can help someone in future